# Error at deploying to Oracle WebLogic from Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, weblogic12c

I'm trying to deploy a web application to a remote WebLogic, and I was following this guide: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/WebLogic+Deployer+Plugin

My servers are:

- Jenkins 2.77
- WebLogicPlugin 4.1
- Oracle WebLogic 12.2.1.2.0

According to the guide, the only thing I need is the **wlthint3client.jar.jar**, but I got the error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.Deployer
```

So searching, I found that there is this **wlfullclient.jar** that was used but Oracle deprecated it. After adding that one, and **weblogic.jar**. I got this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.deploy.api.spi.DeploymentOptions
```

I built the **wlfullclient.jar** by this command:

```
java -jar wljarbuilder.jar
```

In the end, I looked at the exceptions I was getting and ended adding the respective jars that had the missing classes, from the WebLogic server libraries.

Now I'm stucked. It doesn't throw an exception, but it holds at this line:

```
[WebLogicDeploymentManagerImpl.getNewConnection():169] : Connecting to admin server at xxxxxx:7001, as user yyyy
```

And never ends.

Answer (score 1):

I've found what it seems to be the problem.

The mentioned guide tells you to use weblogic.jar, but this only has references to other jars in the WebLogic installation directory.
It's now obvious that it wouldn't work because I don't have the WebLogic and Jenkins in the same machine, so I was trying to run it with incomplete dependencies.

That WebLogicPlugin Guide assumes that they actually are in the same server, so that's the problem. It sucks.

I think I'm going to put all the jars and libraries in the Jenkins server.

Comment: Forget about copying jars and libraries. There is a ton of it and I cannot figure out which are the needed ones. You should have to copy all WL server installations, that's no solution.

Comment: Why don't you use a Jenkins Slave on the remote machine and then run the deploy from there. You don't need to copy the WebLogic libraries around. You can still access the deployer (also tends to be a bit quicker than uploading the full deployment remotely).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that. I'm following this guide here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows
but only says about windows machines with graphic interface.
Is there a way to run this in a linux machine, console only?